# Determination of the location of a specific operator in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Assume that I have a cluster of machines with different powers (i.e. different CPU, Memory, etc.). Is there any way to determine the location of a specific operator (or maybe task) to run? Is it possible to change the default running location of an operator?

I read about "Task chaining and resource groups". However, I think it is not solve my problem.

Is there any specific configuration in Flink? if no, What part of code may relates to this assumption?

Comment: This looks like a question for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: the best that Flink does is to allow you to use `someStream.filter(...).slotSharingGroup("name");` as you might have seen at https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/#task-chaining-and-resource-groups. And it is not a "must do" for the specific group. It only tries if it can. Because it follows the approach to deploy your job whenever is possible....

Answer (score 1):

The taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots property can be an avenue to indicating the relative working capacity of different taskmanagers. You would likely have to adjust both the taskSlots and the memory allocation options based on the resources available resources on the machine.

Personally though, I prefer to address this type of problem with containers, like docker. That way, you can have all of your taskmanagers configure the same, and let the orchestration tools in your container system worry about assigning more or fewer virtual instances to a physical machine base on available resources.

Comment: Of-course I think using containers is good solution. However, for some purposes I want to manege my resources manually. I want to manually choose an operator with specific properties run on a specific machine. I don't know it is in the responsibility of Job manager or Resource manager. But I want to know who decide which operator is run on which machine (or task manger)? @CantankerousBullMoose

Answer (score 0):

Each bunch of task can be tagged to some name and id as below:

```
inputStream
 .map()
 .keyBy()
 .window()
 .reduce()
 .name("enriching customer orders info")
 .uid("enriching customer orders info")
```

this way each operator can be identified uniquely
you can see these names in DAG

hope this helps.